# flash 8 text-to-symbol has incorrect letter and line spacing when published

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-8

I'm creating a Flash animation that must be Flash 8, AS2. Part of the animation requires text to fade-in and fade-out. I've figured out that to achieve this in Flash 8, I have to convert the text to a graphic symbol.

When I view this graphic symbol of text in the editor window, everything looks great. But when I publish it as a .swf file, the letter-spacing of the text is huge and the line-spacing is very small.

Is this a common problem? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to create outlines of the font in Illustrator, then use the paths in Fireworks. So no real solution, just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [embedding the fonts](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/885514-AS2-AS3-Embedding-Fonts-to-be-Used-by-a-Dynamically-Created-TextField) & setting anti alias for animation property for the text box might help.

The only downside of embedding is that the file size increases.